# Content Security Policy in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, content-security-policy, nonce

Has anyone successfully added a CSP to a Nuxt app?

I tried [Helmet](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/csp/) but it doesn't seem to be compatible with a nuxt.config.js file.

Also tried adding csp on the [Render property](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-render/#csp) in Nuxt, but ran into issues when certain scripts required a nonce.

Here is the gist of my Render property in my nuxt.config.js, is this about right?

And how do you go about generating a nonce in Nuxt?

```
render: {
  csp: {
    hashAlgorithm: 'sha256',
    policies: {
      'script-src': [
        'self',
        'unsafe-inline',
        'http://assets.adobedtm.com',
        'https://cdn.polyfill.io/',
        'https://www.everestjs.net',
        'https://www.google-analytics.com',
        'http://localhost:8001',
        "'sha256-<hash>'"
      ],
    },
    reportOnly: false,
    addMeta: true
  }
},
```

Comment: can you please share how you fixed this issue?

Answer (score 1):

First off ensure that in your `nuxt.config.js` you have set the following:

```
render: { csp: true }
```

Here's a module which achieves that. Note that it is not well-tested at the moment.

```js
import { randomBytes } from 'crypto'

export default function cspModule() {
  // Set nuxt CSP options.
  this.options.render.csp = {
    reportOnly: true,
    hashAlgorithm: 'sha256',
  }

  this.nuxt.hook('render:routeContext', (nuxtContext) => {
    // Generate a 128 bit random nonce every request.
    const nonce = randomBytes(16).toString('base64')
    // Inject nonce into vuex state before state is serialized into window.__NUXT__.
    nuxtContext.state.nonce = nonce
  })

  this.nuxt.hook(
    'render:route',
    (url, { cspScriptSrcHashes }, { nuxt: nuxtContext }) => {
      // Extract nonce generated in render:routeContext.
      const nonce = nuxtContext.state.nonce
      // Add nonce to cspScriptSrcHashes. Nuxt will populate all entries in this array
      // to the csp header and meta tags as part of the script-src csp policy.
      cspScriptSrcHashes.push(`'nonce-${nonce}'`)
    }
  )
}
```

One caveat of this method is that the nonce is only for the `script-src` csp policy. But in most cases it is only needed for scripts anyways.

[Source](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6811#issuecomment-637403583)

---

Please keep in mind that having a nonce ("number only used once") only makes sense for SSR, since it must be unique on every request. For SSG (ie `nuxt generate`) this is much harder to achieve (perhaps using a transform on the web server or an edge function?).

[more info](https://content-security-policy.com/nonce/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [nuxt-helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-helmet) which does this for you. It's a really easy package to integrate with just a few lines added to your `nuxt.config.js`.